# WSS 3.0 site -where to store images and CSS files?

Tags: sharepoint

I am creating a WSS 3.0 site and am not sure where to store images and CSS files.

I am thinking of creating a document library and adding 2 subfolders for images and CSS files.

Would that be a good practice? Or should I create 2 document libraries for the images and CSS files (instead of subfolders)?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are these images being used - are they part of the site template/design, and how many users do you have?

If you are deploying "branding" to change the sharepoint look and feel then you should probably deploy these as a sharepoint feature for better performance and easier maintenance. When you upload these files into the document library you will generate additional database calls. Features are served from disk on the IIS application running sharepoint which is less costly. Whether you need to go to this effort depends on your answer to the question above.

Comment: Hi Brian thank you for your answer. We do not run MOSS -only WSS 3.0. In addition, we use a shared hosting (Alentus) so we are rather limited.

"Are they part of the site template/design?" These images will be referenced from the masterpage (default.master) of a site collection.

"How many users do you have?" The site is an Internet-facing, anonymous access, CMS-enabled site.

Thank you again for your help.